# Distributing Tensorflow on Apache Ignite

Tags: tensorflow, ignite

Like Ray and horovod, I want to run tensorflow distributed using the Apache Ignite framework, but I can't seem to find good examples on how to achieve distributed training.
Are there any good notebooks or tutorials out there?

Answer (score 1):

The use of TensorFlow w/Ignite or GridGain community edition is described here: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/integrations/tensorflow/deep-learn-tensor

More information could be found here: https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/tree/master/modules/tensorflow

Comment: Thanks Alex, I reviewed those websites and also found this https://github.com/dmitrievanthony/distributed-training. I'm currently having problems with the ignite-tf.sh commands where it keeps giving me errors. Not sure what the fields mean.